# How can I determine my version of Selenium from the `selenium-webdriver` gem?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Mozilla has [this handy chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html) indicating which specific versions of geckodriver, selenium, and firefox work well together for automated browser testing.

[image]

My version of geckodriver and firefox are easy enough to determine (`geckodriver --version` and `firefox --version`).

But how do I find **what version of "Selenium" is installed** on my Ubuntu installation?

**I am using the [`selenium-webdriver`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/rb) ruby gem** that is officially supported by the SeleniumHQ project, so I'm not sure if that supports a way determining the Selenium library version it is using.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi I don't what's the corresponding command in Linux but for windows I type `gem list selenium-webdriver` and it will tell me the version of selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Thanks @Rajagopalan - However I'm not looking for the *gem* version, I'm looking for the version of the Selenium library it's using.

Comment: It looks like the gem version for `selenium-webdriver` maps to the version of the ruby bindings: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/CHANGES

Comment: I gave you the comment which gives you the selenium version. `gem list selenium-webdriver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem version is going to be the same as the Selenium version.  You can see in the [CHANGELOG for the Ruby gem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/rb/CHANGES) that there are periodic updates ala:

- "* No changes in Ruby bindings for this release"
- "No Ruby changes in this release."

These are simply there to keep the two versions synced.  You can see similar updates in the Python documentation.